# Laravel: Property [user] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel

In Laravel, I've Orders model where each order belongs to only one user,

I want to return only user names and orders ids when I fetch the orders, So in my OrdersController I've this function

```
public function getAllOrders()
    {
        $orders = Order::all();
        return new OrderResource($orders);
    }
```

and in my OrderResource I've

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'user' => $this->user,
            'id' => $this->id,
        ];
    }
```

I'm getting an error saying  `Property [user] does not exist on this collection instance`.

I think the reason is coming from the fact that `$orders` is a collection and I should loop through it and get for each order get the user associated with it, but I've no idea how to do that.

> **Note**: I'm using oneToMany and belongsTo on Users and Orders Model. so orders table doesn't have a `user` column, I want to get the user from the relationship.

Comment: Did my answer solved your issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a collection use like this;

```
public function getAllOrders()
{
    return OrderResource::collection(Order::all());
}
```

When using a model use like this;

```
public function getOrder($id)
{
    return new OrderResource(Order::find($id));
}
```

More information in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources#concept-overview

---

Note: To avoid **N+1** queries, you should get your orders like this; `Order::with('user')->get();` instead of `Order::all()`

The difference is that `Order::with('user')->get();` will perform two queries.

- `select * from orders`
- `select * from users where id in (?, ?, ?, ?, ...)`

Whereas `Order::all()` will perform N+1 queries (N = number of orders)

- `select * from orders`
- `select * from users where id = ?`
- `select * from users where id = ?`
- `select * from users where id = ?`
- ... and so on